# Does a floating point format's width option exclude the decimal point when it's the last element?

Tags: c, format, number-formatting

I'm reading this document about the secret of printf in order to write my own printf and I found the 2nd `("%5.0f.", e)` with **e = 2.718281828** [printf floating point format and what it produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HePOQ.png) confusing, why is there four spaces before the 3 and the decimal point?

I thought the output would be 3. with three spaces before the number 3 as the decimal point takes one space itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the format string `"%5.0f."` there are two parts: a floating point specifier `%5.0f` and a literal `.`.  The two are not attached in any way.

The first part prints 4 spaces followed by the number `2`, and the second part just prints `.` independently of the first part.